# two level sorting of a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
 {"id": 1, "score": some_score.. othe values}
 {"id": 1, "score": some_differetscore.. othe values}  
 {"id": 22, "score": some_score.. othe values}
 {"id": 3, "score": some_score.. othe values}
```

What I am hoping to get is to iterate thru this list in such a way that it is sorted as follows.

The list is sorted by "id" and then reverse sorted with "score"

So all the entries with "id" 1 are clubbed together and then the entry with the topmost score is at the top??
How do i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda d: (d["id"], -d["score"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Effectively the same, but cleaner and unit-testable:

```
def weight(data):
    """We sort the data first by its ID, then by descending score."""
    return data["id"], -data["score"]

sorted(mylist, key=weight)
```